# recorrer un array varias veces con javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array:

```
var array = [5, 2, 3, 1];
```

Tengo que recorrerlo y buscar el número mayor para restarle 1:

```
  var numMayor = Math.max(...array);

  for (var i = 0; i < array[0]; i++) {

    if (array[i] == numMayor) {
      array[i] = array[i]-1;
      console.log(i + "-->" +array);
    }
    console.log(i+ " "+array);
  }
```

El problema es que esto solo me lo hace una vez. Es decir, me está recorriendo todas las posiciones, pero yo necesito que vuelva a recorrerlas para que vuelva a encontrar el mayor y le reste 1 a este hasta que queden todas las posiciones a 1.

Esto es lo que me devuelve:

```
0-->4,2,3,1,0
js.js:15 0 4,2,3,1
js.js:15 1 4,2,3,1
js.js:15 2 4,2,3,1
js.js:15 3 4,2,3,1
```

La salida debería ser la siguiente:

```
0 --> 4,2,3,1
1 --> 3,2,3,1
2 --> 2,2,2,1
3 --> 1,1,1,1
```

En la primera iteración le hemos restado 1 al mayor (al 4). 
En la segunda iteración le hemos restado 1 al mayor (de nuevo al 4).
En la tercera iteración le hemos restado 1 a los dos mayores (al 4 de nuevo y al 3).
Y en la cuarta le hemos restado 1 a todos los 2.

Comment: ¿Cuántas veces debes recorrer el `Array`? ¿En cada corrida siempre le restarás una unidad al mayor? ¿Tienes un ejemplo de entrada y salida?. Saludos

Comment: Debo recorrerlo hasta que quede la mínima diferencia entre cada pareja restando 1 a cada posición tantas veces como sea la primera posición del array (en este caso 5). En este caso, el ejemplo de salida sería el siguiente (pongo en la pregunta).

Comment: Si colocas el cálculo de *numMayor* dentro del bucle, tendrías una primera aproximación, lo que falta es verificar que ya has alcanzado lo que llamas *mínima diferencia*.

Comment: El cálculo de la mínima diferencia por ahora no me preocupa. El problema es que no puedo ir restando a cada valor porque solo recorro el array una vez.

Comment: Colocando el numMayor dentro del bucle, hace lo mismo.

Comment: Claro, igual yo usaría un bucle de tipo `while` en vez de un bucle `for`. Pero no me queda claro lo de la mínima diferencia, es decir, las diferencias entre cada par de elementos contiguos debe ser un valor específico ¿(1 por ejemplo)?

Comment: Sí, creo que me has entendido, de todas formas lo que más me interesa es que el array se recorra varias veces restando 1 a la posición que mayor valor tenga en cada iteración. Para no complicarlo, vamos a suponer que se tienen que quedar todas a 1. [1,1,1,1]

Answer (score 2):

Una primera aproximación a la solución es usar un bucle `while` en vez de un bucle `for`, y dicho bucle lo ejecutaremos tantas veces indique el primer elemento de nuestro `Array`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const array = [5, 2, 3, 1, 0];
let iteracion = array[0];

while(iteracion > 0) {
  console.log(`Iteración: ${iteracion--}`);
}
```

Ahora, debemos hallar el elemento mayor dentro del `array` y restarle una unidad. Para ello usamos el método [`max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/max) del Objeto [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math), y a dicho elemento le restamos una unidad.

Para saber cuál es este elemento, usaremos el método [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf) del Objeto [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array).

Una aproximación sería la siguiente:

```js
const array = [5, 2, 3, 1, 0];
let iteracion = array[0];

while(iteracion > 0) {
  let mayor = Math.max(...array);
  let indice = array.indexOf(mayor);
  array[indice]-= 1;
  console.log(`${iteracion} => ${array}`);
  iteracion--;
}
```

Con esto ya estarías recorriendo el `Array` la cantidad de veces indicadas por su primera posición y restando en cada iteración una unidad al elemento de mayor magnitud.

**EDICIÓN**

Como en tu pregunta dices que necesitas restar una unidad al mayor pero agregas que si hay más de 2 valores iguales que son mayores, entonces refactorizamos nuestra función para tomar en cuenta ese detalle:

```js
const array = [5, 2, 3, 1, 0];
let iteracion = array[0];

while(iteracion > 0) {
  let mayor = Math.max(...array);
  while(array.indexOf(mayor) >= 0) {
    let indice = array.indexOf(mayor);
    array[indice]-= 1;
  }
  console.log(`${iteracion} => ${array}`);
  iteracion--;
}
```

Con esto ya estarías restando 1 unidad a todos los mayores en una misma iteración.

Falta establecer lo de la diferencia mínima que comentas en tu pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!  Me viene perfecto para seguir!!!

Answer (score 1):

intenta con un while y un contador

```
var contador = Math.max(...array);

while (contador =! 0){

    for (var i = 0, i++) {
        maxv=Math.max(...array);
        if (array[i] ==maxv ) {
            array[i] = array[i]-1;
            console.log(i + "-->" +array);
    }
    console.log(i+ " "+array);
    contador=-1


}
```

Disculpa los errores del código, hace mucho tiempo que no escribo en javascript,
Pero la idea es que la lista se recorra un número igual al valor máximo inicial encontrado en la lista (contador). Y en tu codigo inicial hace falta ese detalle

Answer (score 1):

podría ser:

```js
let array = [5, 2, 3, 1];

while(array.find(arr => arr !== 1)) {
  const major = Math.max(...array)
  array = array.map(a => a === major ? --a : a)
  console.log(array)
}
```

Comment: Muy bueno el código, falta la explicación. Se considera de baja calidad responder sólo con código. Saludos